# Combining two lists to form a dictionary

Tags: python, excel, dictionary

I have extracted the data I need from two columns of an excel sheet as two lists. When I try to combine these two lists into a dictionary, the final output has only 300 entries whereas my excel sheet has about 1200 entries. Why aren't all the entries being stored in the dictionary?

Here's my code:

```
import xlrd

xl_workbook = xlrd.open_workbook("my_doc.xls")
sheet1 = xl_workbook.sheet_by_index(0)

list1 = sheet1.col_values(2)
list2 = sheet1.col_values(3)

data = dict(zip(list1, list2))
```

I tried printing lengths of list1, list2, and data to cross-check.

Comment: Are you sure there are no repeated entries in `list1`?

Comment: Just realized there were multiple repeated entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) can only contain unique keys. Check the length of `set(list1)` to see how many unique keys you have.

Comment: So if I need all entries to be present in my output, what would the best way to go? I need each entry in list1 to correspond to each entry in list2

Comment: What should `data[repeated_entry]` return in your opinion?

Comment: I need my final output to be an excel sheet with two columns - list1 and list2 - with all 1200 entries.

Comment: why even bother making a dictionary then? Why not just have a list of tuples?

Comment: I want to use it at a later stage to loop through :-/ But I guess I'll make a list of tuples for now.

Comment: @alapalak Great, especially since you can loop through lists just as well. I think Lunaweaver's answer to your original question is correct, though, so please consider ticking it off, so they get the credit they deserve.